# How can i solve Ajax Ckeditor value post problem

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send a CKeditor value post with ajax but i cant response anyway! I cant find anything

```
function send_days(tourId){

    var url = baseUrl + "tour/save_days/" + tourId;
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances.tour_textarea_days.getData();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            data: dataString,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache:false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('.tour_popup_container').html(data);
            }
        });
}
```

but when i chance ajax method like this. It is succesfull

```
 $.post(url, {data:value}, function (response) {
        $('.tour_popup_container').html(response);

    })
```

here is my codeigniter php file (it is not important actually)

```
public function save_days($tourId)
    {

        $value=$this->input->post("data");
        print_r($value);
    }
```

Comment: if you are using php just submit your data as a `form` and received on other ends then you can get data as you get other variables in PHP and save in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used dataString instead of value.

```
var url = baseUrl + "tour/save_days/" + tourId;
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances.tour_textarea_days.getData();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            data: value /*dataString*/,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache:false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('.tour_popup_container').html(data);
            }
        });
```